# update_term_meta() only updating once on certain meta keys

Tags: php, custom-field, taxonomy, terms, term-meta

I set up 4 custom meta fields on a custom taxonomy, and for some reason the field values for my 2 text fields only update the first time they are added to the database. Either from including them in the "add" form or if I create a taxonomy without them and then include them in the "edit" form for the first time. But as soon as I try to change the values, the database does not get updated. What am I doing wrong?

Here is my code:

```
// Add the fields to the "groups" taxonomy, using our callback function  
add_action( 'groups_add_form_fields', 'groups_taxonomy_custom_fields', 10, 2 ); // "Add new" form
add_action( 'groups_edit_form_fields', 'groups_taxonomy_custom_fields', 10, 2 ); // "Edit" form
function groups_taxonomy_custom_fields($term) {
    // Get the page
    global $pagenow;

    // Set empty vars
    $organization = '';
    $email_domain = '';
    $facilitators = array();
    $access_ids = array();

    // If we are on the "add new" page
    if ($pagenow == 'edit-tags.php') {
        // Table setup
        $cont1 = '<div class="form-field">';
        $cont2 = '';
        $cont3 = '</div>';
        
    // If we are on the "edit" term page
    } elseif ($pagenow == 'term.php') {
        // Check for existing taxonomy meta for the term you're editing
        $term_id = isset($term->term_id) ? $term->term_id : null;
        $organization = get_term_meta( $term_id, 'organization', true );
        $email_domain = get_term_meta( $term_id, 'email_domain', true );
        if (get_term_meta( $term_id, 'facilitators', true )) {
            $facilitators = get_term_meta( $term_id, 'facilitators', true );
        }
        if (get_term_meta( $term_id, 'access_ids', true )) {
            $access_ids = get_term_meta( $term_id, 'access_ids', true );
        }

        // Table setup
        $cont1 = '<tr class="form-field">  
        <th scope="row" valign="top">';
        $cont2 = '</th>  
        <td>';
        $cont3 = '</td>  
        </tr>';
        
    // Else nothing
    } else {
        $cont1 = '';
        $cont2 = '';
        $cont3 = '';
    }

    // Let's get all the webinar codes
    $codes = get_terms( array(
        'taxonomy' => eri_access_id_taxonomy(),
        'hide_empty' => false,
        'order' => 'DESC',
    ) );

    // Now get all the Facilitators
    $users = get_users( array(
        'role__in'  => array( 'facilitator' ),
        'orderby'   => 'display_name',
        'order'     => 'ASC'
    ) );
    ?>  

    <!-- ADD SOME CSS -->
    <style>
    .yoast-notification {
        display: none;
    }
    .editor-training-groups-list {
        background: white;
        max-height: 20em;
        overflow: hidden;
        padding-left: 6px;
        padding-top: 6px;
        width: 94%;
        overflow-y:auto;
    }
    .editor-training-groups-choice {
        margin-bottom: 10px;
        float: left;
        clear: both;
    }
    .editor-code-label {
        vertical-align: top !important;
        display: inline !important;
    }
    .training-type-title {
        font-weight: bold;
        float: left;
        clear: both;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
    }
    </style>

    <!-- ORGANIZATION FIELD -->
    <?php echo $cont1; ?>   
        <label for="organization"><?php _e('Organization/Group'); ?></label>  
    <?php echo $cont2 ?? $cont2; ?>  
        <input type="text" name="organization" id="organization" size="25" value="<?php echo $organization; ?>"><br />  
        <span class="description"><?php _e('The full name of the organization or group.'); ?></span>  
    <?php echo $cont3; ?>

    <!-- EMAIL DOMAIN FIELD -->
    <?php echo $cont1; ?>  
        <label for="email_domain"><?php _e('Email Domain'); ?></label>  
    <?php echo $cont2 ?? $cont2; ?> 
        <input type="text" name="email_domain" id="email_domain" size="25" value="<?php echo $email_domain; ?>"><br />  
        <span class="description"><?php _e('Your organization\'s email domain name  (after the @ symbol) that users will mostly be using to register. (NOTE: Anybody who registers using an email address with this domain will be automatically added to this training group.)'); ?></span>  
    <?php echo $cont3; ?>

    <!-- FACILITATORS FIELD -->
    <?php echo $cont1; ?>  
        <span><?php _e('Facilitators'); ?></span>
    <?php echo $cont2 ?? $cont2; ?> 
        <div class="editor-training-groups-list">
            <?php
            // Vars
            $the_users_checked = [];
            $the_users = [];

            // Cycle through each user
            foreach ($users as $user) {
                $is_checked = false;
                $checked = '';
                if (in_array($user->ID, $facilitators)) {
                    $is_checked = true;
                    $checked = ' checked="checked"';
                }

                $id = '<div class="editor-training-groups-choice">
                    <input type="hidden" value="0" name="facilitators['.$user->ID.']">
                    <input type="checkbox" id="facilitators['.$user->ID.']" name="facilitators['.$user->ID.']" value="1" '.$checked.'/><label for="facilitators['.$user->ID.']" class="editor-code-label">'.$user->display_name.' <span class="limit-length">('.$user->user_email.'): '.$user->organization.'</span></label>
                </div>';

                if ($is_checked) {
                    $the_users_checked[] = $id;
                } else {
                    $the_users[] = $id;
                }
            }

            echo implode('', $the_users_checked);
            echo implode('', $the_users);
            ?>
        </div>  
        <span class="description"><?php _e('Select the Facilitators that will have access to this training\s dashboard.'); ?></span>  
    <?php echo $cont3; ?>

    <!-- TRAININGS FIELD -->
    <?php echo $cont1; ?>  
        <span><?php _e('Trainings'); ?></span>
    <?php echo $cont2 ?? $cont2; ?> 
        <div class="editor-training-groups-list">
            <?php
            // Let's get all of the codes to create a link
            $tta_names = [];
            foreach ($codes as $code) {
                $code_names[] = strtolower($code->name);
            }

            // Create empty arrays to store them
            $tta_names = [];
            $ita_names = [];
            $uta_names = [];
            $tta_checked = [];
            $ita_checked = [];
            $uta_checked = [];
            $tta = [];
            $ita = [];
            $uta = [];

            // Cycle through each term
            foreach ($codes as $code) {
                $is_checked = false;
                $checked = '';
                if (in_array($code->name, $access_ids)) {
                    $is_checked = true;
                    $checked = ' checked="checked"';
                }
                $code_title = get_the_title( $code->description );
                $li = '<div class="editor-training-groups-choice">
                    <input type="hidden" value="0" name="access_ids['.$code->name.']">
                    <input type="checkbox" id="access_ids['.$code->name.']" name="access_ids['.$code->name.']" value="1" '.$checked.'/><label for="access_ids['.$code->name.']" class="editor-code-label">'.$code->name.': <span class="limit-length">'.$code_title.'</span></label>
                </div>';
                
                if (eri_is_TTA($code->name)) {
                    $tta_names[] = strtolower($code->name);
                    if ($is_checked) {
                        $tta_checked[] = $li;
                    } else {
                        $tta[] = $li;
                    }
                } elseif (eri_is_ITA($code->name)) {
                    $ita_names[] = strtolower($code->name);
                    if ($is_checked) {
                        $ita_checked[] = $li;
                    } else {
                        $ita[] = $li;
                    }
                } elseif (eri_is_UTA($code->name)) {
                    $uta_names[] = strtolower($code->name);
                    if ($is_checked) {
                        $uta_checked[] = $li;
                    } else {
                        $uta[] = $li;
                    }
                }
            }

            // Title Extension
            $title_ext = ' Technical Assistance';
            $top_margin = '30px';
            $target = "_blank";

            // Add the title and list items
            if (!empty($tta_checked) || !empty($tta)) {
                echo '<div class="training-type-title">Targeted'.$title_ext.': <a href="/wp-admin/edit.php?post_type=page&codes='.implode('%2C',$tta_names).'" target="'.$target.'">('.count($tta_names).')</a></div>';

                echo implode('', $tta_checked);
                echo implode('', $tta);
            }

            if (!empty($ita_checked) || !empty($ita)) {
                $margin = (!empty($tta_checked) || !empty($tta)) ? ' style="margin-top: '.$top_margin.'"' : '';
                echo '<div class="training-type-title"'.$margin.'>Intensive'.$title_ext.': <a href="/wp-admin/edit.php?post_type=page&codes='.implode('%2C',$ita_names).'" target="'.$target.'">('.count($ita_names).')</a></div>';

                echo implode('', $ita_checked);
                echo implode('', $ita);
            }

            if (!empty($uta_checked) || !empty($uta)) {
                $margin = (!empty($tta_checked) || !empty($tta)) || (!empty($ita_checked) || !empty($ita)) ? ' style="margin-top: '.$top_margin.'"' : '';
                echo '<div class="training-type-title"'.$margin.'>Universal'.$title_ext.': <a href="/wp-admin/edit.php?post_type=post&codes='.implode('%2C',$uta_names).'" target="'.$target.'">('.count($uta_names).')</a></div>';

                echo implode('', $uta_checked);
                echo implode('', $uta);
            }
            ?>
        </div>  
        <span class="description"><?php _e('Select the Webinar Codes this Training Group has access to.'); ?></span>  
    <?php echo $cont3; ?>

    <?php
}  

// Save the changes made on the "groups" taxonomy, "add new" form
add_action( 'created_groups', 'save_groups_new_custom_fields', 10, 2 );
function save_groups_new_custom_fields( $term_id, $tt_id ) {  
    if ( isset($_POST['organization']) ) {  
        add_term_meta( $term_id, 'organization', $_POST['organization'], true );
    }
    if ( isset($_POST['email_domain']) ) {  
        add_term_meta( $term_id, 'email_domain', $_POST['email_domain'], true );
    }
    if ( isset($_POST['access_ids']) ) {
        $aid_checked = [];
        $access_ids = $_POST['access_ids'];
        foreach ($access_ids as $key=>$value) {
            if ($value == '1'){
                $aid_checked[] = $key;
            }
        }
        add_term_meta( $term_id, 'access_ids', $aid_checked );
    }
    if ( isset($_POST['facilitators']) ) {
        $fac_checked = [];
        $facilitators = $_POST['facilitators'];
        foreach ($facilitators as $key=>$value) {
            if ($value == '1'){
                $fac_checked[] = $key;
            }
        }
        add_term_meta( $term_id, 'facilitators', $fac_checked );
    }
}
// Save the changes made on the "groups" taxonomy, "edit" form
add_action( 'edited_groups', 'save_groups_existing_custom_fields', 10, 2 ); 
function save_groups_existing_custom_fields( $term_id, $tt_id ) {  
    if ( isset($_POST['organization']) ) {
        update_term_meta( $term_id, 'organization', $_POST['organization'], true ); // <-- ONLY UPDATING ONCE
    }
    if ( isset($_POST['email_domain']) ) {
        update_term_meta( $term_id, 'email_domain', $_POST['email_domain'], true ); // <-- ONLY UPDATING ONCE
    }
    if ( isset($_POST['access_ids']) ) {
        $aid_checked = [];
        $access_ids = $_POST['access_ids'];
        foreach ($access_ids as $key=>$value) {
            if ($value == '1'){
                $aid_checked[] = $key;
            }
        }
        update_term_meta( $term_id, 'access_ids', $aid_checked );
    }
    if ( isset($_POST['facilitators']) ) {
        $fac_checked = [];
        $facilitators = $_POST['facilitators'];
        foreach ($facilitators as $key=>$value) {
            if ($value == '1'){
                $fac_checked[] = $key;
            }
        }
        update_term_meta( $term_id, 'facilitators', $fac_checked );
    }
}
```

Interestingly enough my checkbox fields are updating fine every single time, so something is going on with the text fields.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out:

```
update_term_meta( $term_id, 'organization', $_POST['organization'], true );
```

should have been

```
update_term_meta( $term_id, 'organization', $_POST['organization'] );
```

Where the fourth parameter makes it unique.